# How to set CachePolicy in cloudfront using CDK's CloudfrontWebDistribution Construct?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I am trying to set **CachePolicy, OriginRequestPolicy and ResponseHeaderPolicy** using [CloudfrontWebDistribution Construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudfront.CloudFrontWebDistribution.html).In the Construct Props for OriginConfigs I am not able to see any option to set any of the 3 mentioned above.
I am aware that, CDK is pushing for using new construct `distribution`  and i can see this construct props supports all 3  policies which are mentioned above.
is there a way to set these using cloudfrontWebDistribution construct ?

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudfront-readme.html#migrating-from-the-original-clo[…]he-newer-distribution-construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudfront-readme.html#migrating-from-the-original-clo%5B%E2%80%A6%5Dhe-newer-distribution-construct)